# Observer.error is not sending the error

Tags: rxjs

I am trying to generate an intermediate service between a request service and the angular component that subscribes to it. To achieve that, I generate an observable from httpClient request that connects with the intermediate service, and sends the HTTP response.

When the response arrives to the intermediate service, I generate another observable that connects with the client component. 
The problem starts here. As I get a `500` status response from request, I get that response in the intermediate service, but when I try to send to the client component with a `subscribe.error(err)` it starts a loop that never ends, getting the following error:

> You provided an invalid object where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable.

I am using the same `observer.error(err)` in the request service and in the intermediate service, and it works correctly only in the request.

```
Request: 
Observable.create((observer: Observer<any>) => 
this.httpClient
        .request(httpRequest)
        .subscribe(
...
(res: HttpErrorResponse) => {
            observer.error(res);
            observer.complete();
          },
          () => {
            observer.complete();
          },
}
Intermediate Service:
Observable.create((observer: Observer<any>) => 
this.requestService.request(requestServiceOptions).subscribe(
...
    (err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
            if (err.status === 401) {
              this.callbackWhenRequestFails();
            } else {
              observer.error(err);
              observer.complete();
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It has been solutionated.
Unfortunately, when catching the error I was using return instead of throw, then that's why the console was showing the stream error!